# Regexp <=/> regular language?

Tags: c#, regex

as I know, a regexp is equivalent with a altenating finite automat (reads one symbol and then comes a transition to the next state)

Than how is it possible, that this regexp works fine in c#?

```
var input = "bla bla bla bla  <I NEED THIS TEXT>";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"<(.*)>");
```

because the machine must stay in the "."-state, whatever comes, mustn't?
I think the right regexp is the following:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"<([^>]*)>");
```

but both work fine.

Comment: I can't see what else you were expecting. What were you expecting?

Comment: That the first doesn't match anything, because the .* reads the whole string - without backtracking.

Comment: Note that the term "regex" has become an established term for a family of languages which contains non-regular dialects. IIRC constructs like zero-width assertions aren't regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backtracking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4.aspx.
When you use code like:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"<(.*)>");
```

Regex engine parses all chars in input string (and parse ">" as ".*" match) and don't find any matches. Then, it comes back in one symbol (last ">") and try to parse it as ">" in pattern. And - it matches! So, it returns right string.

Comment: Then it's not equivalent with an automat!

Comment: Why so? Automat could be deterministic/nondeteministic. And, as described in my link, .NET Regex engine is Nondeterministic finite-state machine.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these regexes performing in the following cases:

**1.**

```
bla bla bla bla  <I NEED THIS TEXT> bla bla bla <I need this text>
```

Here the first regex matches `<I NEED THIS TEXT> bla bla bla <I need this text>` all at once, not caring about that there is text in between the two "tags".

The second regex will match `<I NEED THIS TEXT>` and `<I need this text>` separately. Hooray. But now look at this:

**2.**

```
bla bla bla bla  <I NEED <something nested in> THIS TEXT>
```

Now regex one matches `<I NEED <something nested in> THIS TEXT>` and regex two matches `<I NEED <something nested in>`. oops.

Now look at this:

**3.**

```
<I NEED THIS TEXT "containing an attribute with ">" in it>
```

Regex 1 matches all; regex 2 matches `<I NEED THIS TEXT "containing an attribute with ">`.

And this is why regular expressions are difficult in situations where you'd normally need a recursive descent parser.

Some modern regex flavors do support arbitrarily recursive nesting, but even then you need to be on your toes because of the possibility of literal strings, comments, embedded scripts and whatnot in HTML/XML etc (which is probably what this question is about in the end, isn't it?)...

Comment: Okay, but my question is, how comes out the 1. "machine" from the "."-state? because the transition is the following: --("<")-->[A]--(.)-->[P]--(.)-->[P]--... There is just a P.-->P transition because of the *.

Comment: This is called backtracking. `.*` first matches the entire string but remembers each character position along the way. If the following token then fails to match, it goes back one character at a time until that's possible again.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that a naive implementation of regular expressions wouldn't work for your example. However, many engines implement [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times), which allows them to reach the end of the input string, determine that a match wasn't made, and then start working *backwards* from the end, discarding any `.` or `+` or `*` matches that had been made too greedily, note the `>` character successful match, and return success quickly.

Other engines don't actually implement backtracking as I've described, but reach the same results through more clever mechanisms.

Comment: With backtraching it is a pushdown automaton, it musts remember to a state before, isn't?